# Faceted Search

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is "faceted search" (drupal.org/project/faceted_search) powerful enough to index and search 100.000 Drupal nodes ?

Comment: 100000 - not so much node count. If you have good server host - no problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not sensible to use for such a site. They warn having more than 5k nodes. I imagine they will create a lot of indexes in a way that doesn't scale.

Your best option is apache solr which was made for this stuff. Something mysql isn't made to be able to handle.

Comment: Can I use a free version of SOLR and install it on my own server ?

Comment: @Patrick, I have answered you that question a week or two ago.